# Tensorflow Slim : Significance of Different versions

Tags: tensorflow, tf-slim

I am trying to use tf slim library for building model on top of inception-v3 model

The tf slim library uses a version '**import tensorflow.contrib.slim** as slim'

wheras the inception model uses '**from inception.slim import slim**'

both the versions have some common and some different set of files , like **layers.py** is not present in inception.slim etc

1. What is the significance of having two versions of the library ?
2. Is there a difference in application of both the libraries
3. The inception.slim contains files with deprecated functions like **tf.op_scope** and **tf.variable_op_scope** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We are moving layers to the core library.
2. There may be subtle differences, the core library is always the recommended one.
3. Yes, while slim/tf.learn etc are being assimilated, they will be in an odd shape until then. (But they should continue to work)

Comment: could you also explain the difference/similarity between tflearn and tf.slim ?? both seem to be high level api's for tf .Thanks

Comment: They used to be different ways of interacting with tensorflow. Technically, slim is a part of tflearn. We are cherry-picking them into the core, and ultimately all functionality at different levels of granularity should be available with the core.